# Powershell (5.1) Install-module or Find-module are hanging / blocked

Tags: windows, powershell

I can't use 'module' related commands in Powershell.
It's hanging with the blinking dash.

For example, I tried :

`Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser`

Or :

`Find-Module -Name PowerShellGet`

Both commands just give me a blinking dash...

So I don't know what to do. Is there a cache, or something ?
Plus, as it's a part of Windows 10, I can't uninstall and reinstall it ?

Thanks.

Windows 10 Family Edition 2004
Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShellGallery has some strange outages and delays for some weeks already, which impacts Find-Module / Install-Module / Find-PSResource / Install-PSResource.

It doesn't affect only you.

More info:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGallery/blob/master/psgallery_status.md
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGallery/issues/132

Even https://powershellgallery.com is down some time.

Comment: ho, OK ! Thank you !

Comment: Wow, I just spent 2 hours digging into this and now was deploying my Google-Fu for help and found this! Thanks for the links.